# Dependency error

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install libstdc++6_6.1.1-9 on ubntu version 14.04, and it show me error like some file will broken because of it . I already tried commands like :
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrad
but it doesnot working

Comment: libstdc++6_6.1.1-9 is an Ubuntu 16.10 package. .... Please edit your post to include your Ubuntu version.

Comment: ubntu version 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Some dependencis can not work on lower versions of linux. There are two options. Upgrade your Ubuntu or use ''aptitude '' since aptitude can have a solution for your situation.